# How can I get both sound and vibration at the same time on my Samsung S4?

Tags: notifications, samsung-galaxy-s-4, vibration

Need some help. I must have pressed something on the settings on my Samsung S4 because when I receive a chat or SMS the phone doesn't vibrate unless I turn off the sound.

So right now I have to choose to eıther have vibration OR sound and I want both at the same time.

Comment: Tried restarting your phone? Is the phone moded?

Answer (score 1):

In the Messaging app, click the left soft key and open `Settings`. Under `Notifications`, make sure `Vibrate` is checked.